# Make internal declarations visible to other modules in Kotlin

Tags: testing, gradle, kotlin, visibility

I have a Kotlin project that uses Gradle for building/testing. In Kotlin you can mark dependencies as `internal`, for example:

```kotlin
internal class MyClass : MyInterface
```

Now, I also want to run some integration tests separated from the normal `test` task in Gradle, so I modified my *build.gradle* as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    testIntegration {
        compileClasspath = files(main.output, project.configurations.testCompileClasspath)
        runtimeClasspath = files(testIntegration.output, main.output, project.configurations.testRuntimeClasspath)
    }
}

task testIntegration(type: Test) {
    group = "Verification"
    description = "Integration tests"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.testIntegration.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.testIntegration.runtimeClasspath

    useTestNG()
}
```

It works fine except if I want to access the internal declaration:

```kotlin
// In my integration tests
val instance = factory.buildInstance()

assertTrue(instance is MyClass) // Compilation fails in this line because `MyClass` is internal
```

Going through the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules) it mentions:

> a Gradle source set (**with the exception that the test source set** can access the internal declarations of main);

How do I tell Gradle that the new `testIntegration` source set should also be able to access `internal` declarations from the `main` source set?